# As API author, should I treat Empty and Null the same in search criteria?

Tags: c#, api-design, null

I have a RESTFUL api, one of the endpoints is receiving search criteria which contains property for "Title".
Should I allow consumers to send either `null` (or eliminate the property) or `Empty` string in this property and deal with both as the same meaning in this context ?
I mean, for me I shouldn't do search with `null`, and in this context doing search with empty will always not return any results.

Or is this up to me and I only need to keep it documented and consistent in all my API ?

Comment: As the API author, it’s completely up to you. There is no right answer to this, only opinions.

Comment: This is what I was thinking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to answer the question: "Is there a difference between an empty title and an unknown title?" in your context.

In a search context, an empty title could mean you're only searching for persons who have no title.

Whereas the absence of title could mean searching for persons regardless of title.

So take your pick: is the difference relevant in your use case.

Answer (score 1):

[Tony Hoare, who introduced `Null` called it his "billion dollar mistake".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare)

You should use something meaningful to your domain instead of null.  An explicit  flag that indicates you don't know something or you want a broader search.  Don't use a low-level programming language mistake for your domain API!

Comment: So in my scenario, if I want to support the empty string. how should I differentiate between those three states: 1. having a value .2. having an empty string .3. I don't want to use this prop in search criteria ?
I see the best way is to send null or omit this prop (which will be converted to null in c# api back-end.

Comment: sql-like null is a very different to pointer-null, that quote is about pointer-null and the question is about sql-like null.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send a `null` over REST. All you can send is strings, e.g. the string "null". `null` is a special value recognized e.g. by an SQL engine or a programming language interpreter. Such tools can distinguish between `null` and "null" (and "").

A REST end point cannot; if you decide to interpret the string "null" as a special case, you can no longer accept that string literally. I would never do that, since clients have no business sending special-purpose values from their own internal representation to an external information provider. If a client means "", they can simply send "" (e.g. `api.com/service?firstname=Beyonce&lastname=`).

You have no idea how many people called "Null" have their lives made miserable by badly programmed data exchange interfaces. Don't compound the problem!

Comment: On what basis do you assume that `lastname=` is passing an empty string for lastname? It’s passing nothing. Whether the endpoint treats that as `null` or “” sounds like an implementation detail to me.

Comment: I think it depends on the back-end language, I'm using C# and it can accept either eliminate the property or send `null` and will except both as `null`.  I'm asking about the difference between sending `null` and `Empty` and if I can treat them the same, not if I can interpret the `null` or eliminating the property.

Comment: what would you call omitting a value if not "sending" a null value?

Comment: You reminded me of this xkcd: https://xkcd.com/327/